# Inserting a Boolean function to validate with 'Yup' library

Tags: javascript, yup

I have this function that is working correctly and returns a Boolean value. I would like to insert this function to validate an input field from the 'Yup' library.

**Here is the function:**
This the function. It is working succesfully.

```
  console.log(isHsCodeAllowed(111111)) //true
  console.log(isHsCodeAllowed(222222)) //false

  function isHsCodeAllowed(hsCode) {
    let status = ''

    const hsCodeList =
      [
        { "number": 111111, "status": "allowed" },
        { "number": 222222, "status": "prohibited" },
        { "number": 333333, "status": "allowed" },
        { "number": 444444, "status": "prohibited" }
      ]

    for (let i = 0; i < hsCodeList.length; i++) {
      if (hsCode === hsCodeList[i]["number"]) {
        status = hsCodeList[i]["status"]
      }
    }

    return status === 'allowed' || false
  }
```

**Here is the place I would like to implement it in 'Yup':**
It does not work. It does not return the validation message.

```
async function validateProduct() {
    try {
      const schema = Yup.object().shape({     
        hsCode: Yup.number()
          .test(isHsCodeAllowed, 'This code is prohibited') // <---------------    
      });
}
```

You can use any method that works or another solution. It is not mandatory to use the 'test' method, but it is mandatory to use the Yup library.

Comment: Why do you have `return status === 'allowed' || false` it's the same as just saying `return status === 'allowed'`

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? Because it seems like you have a try statement without a catch block and without a closing bracket. Or is the rest of the code just removed for brevity

Comment: I simply like to do this way. The code stay more legible in my opinion. But somethimes I work in your proposed way.

Comment: Ok...it doesn't really make sense, but it doesn't mess with the functionality of the code. I would still recommend that you stop doing this...it just makes the code more wordy and confusing.

Comment: YesI t is the rest of the code just removed for brevity. I have been separeated the only userful code to solve the problem and it cause some omissions and apparently syntax error.

Comment: Ok, can you add the error message or describe the exact problem? "it isn't working" isn't very useful

Comment: I will do this after I have the solution of the problem

Comment: Can you add the code where you call the verification?....The error might be there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedtestname-string-message-string--function-test-function-schema

The `.test` function takes two string parameters at the beginning an then the validator function.

```js
const schema = Yup.object().shape({     
    hsCode: Yup
        .number()
        .test('is-allowed-HsCode', 'This code is prohibited', isHsCodeAllowed)    
});
```

Also throw a ValidationError in your validator function:

```js
function isHsCodeAllowed(hsCode) {
    const hsCodeList = [
        { "number": 111111, "status": "allowed" },
        { "number": 222222, "status": "prohibited" },
        { "number": 333333, "status": "allowed" },
        { "number": 444444, "status": "prohibited" }
    ];

    const status = hsCodeList.find(c => c.number === hsCode)?.status;

    return status === 'allowed';
}
```

Comment: I implemented your solution and it didn't work. Did you forget something? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but "it didn't work" doesn't really tell me what the problem is...can you please post the exact error message, or describe what exactly isn't working.

Comment: There isn't appear the validation error message below the form field when I put some invalid value for the requisition .

Comment: Then the problem is most likely how you handle the validation error: Please post the code where you handle the message

Comment: The code is the same as the one I showed, but with more items.
When I put something different from 'test', it works. Like that: hsCode: Yup.string()
          .min(6, 'Must be exactly 6 digits')
          .max(6, 'Must be exactly 6 digits')
When I put some test function, it doesn't work like this: 
 .test(
            'is-222222',
            "this isn't the number i want",
            (val) => val != 222222
          )

Comment: Try throwing a ValidationError in your isHsCodeAllowed function

Comment: Please tell me how to do this

Comment: There appears an error Message:  'ValidationError' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: You would have to import it from yup

Comment: It continues not working. There isn't appear any validation message that have to do with this function

Comment: I just tested it myself and it does work, so please post all of the code in your question because the problem lies not in the code that you showed so far.

Comment: Thank you for the support. I noticed what was the real cause of the problem. There in my code, was happening a conflict with the validadion of HSCode happening in the another place. Thank you.